# Combining multiple verbs

Tags: relative-clauses, formality, casual

I work in a hotel and I was asking a coworker if we are permitted to drink the coffee in a certain location near the desk.  I am trying to be formal with this request.

I asked "Are we allowed to take that coffee?"

In romanji "Sore Koohii o teru kyoka sa retamasu ka"

1) Am I allowed to combine verbs like this?  Under what circumstance can I do this?

2) In order to be polite is it ok to add the masu to the last verb or do I have to add it to Teru as well?

3) How would I make this sentence casual?

Comment: Question, is this coworker at the same hierarchical level as you? Is he perhaps your senpai? That will help people answer things related to politeness

Comment: No this coworker is my friend we are on the same "level" (bottom feeders).  We are both kohai I guess.  She speaks with me casually but since I am a new Japanese learner I am focusing on the formal language to avoid ever offending some one.

Comment: What did you intend by "teru"? It doesn't remind me a relevant word from the context. btw... there's no "we're both kohai" more than "we're both younger than each other", it's a relative concept.

Comment: I suppose the most likely candidate for what "teru" was meant to be is 取る.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to ask. Do you want to ask if you are allowed to drink coffee at a certain location, or do you want to ask if you are allowed to take coffee from a certain location?

Comment: It coffee for customers.  But I am trying to sneak some.